# Why can I access HTML element without runat=server from server side?

Tags: asp.net

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<script runat="server">
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myTr.Visible = false;
        mySpan.Visible = false;
    }
</script>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <table runat="server">
            <tr id="myTr">
                <td>Hello</td>
                <td><span id="mySpan">World</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Hi</td>
                <td>Bye</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Notice `myTr` and `mySpan` **both don't have runat=server**, but compiler only gives error on `mySpan.Visible = false`.

[image]

Why doesn't compiler report error on `myTr.Visible = false`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you are able to access your `tr` because the table runs at server and the `tr` is part of the table itself.

On the other way, the `span` element is only accessible from the client because it's not been rendered on the server side.

if you add an id to some td for the table you'll be able to access it also on the server side script. However if you remove the `runat="server"` from the table you'll get build errors when trying to access the table components.

```
<table runat="server">
    <tr id="myTr">
        <td id="myTd">Hello</td> <%--This td is also accessible from the server script--%>
        <td><span id="mySpan">World</span></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

> UPDATE:
>   OK, It's not a guess anymore. According to the great explanation from Michael Amundsen and Paul Litwin on their book [ASP.NET for Developers](https://books.google.com.uy/books?id=kxL-ozksT7oC&pg=PA136&lpg=PA128&dq=table+runat%3Dserver+can+access+tr+and+td&source=bl&ots=HkujuqexRt&sig=yhYw0UhCr_hwxMmPUvhklQb2RXw&hl=es-419&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj1o7WQtLfVAhUBDpAKHflYDr0Q6AEIZzAI#v=onepage&q&f=false). You can see the reason there.

**Summarizing here as per your comment also:** 
On page 136, subtitle: Table Header (Th), Row (Tr) and Detail (Td) it says: You  can also use server-side code to manipulate the th, tr and td tags of a table. **Listing 8.9 Manipulating Th, Tr and Td Tags Using Server-Side Code** is very similar to yours.

Basically a table with a `runat="server"` and `th`, `tr` and `td` elements with id attributes only (no runat="server") that are effectively accessed from the `Page_Load` event handler on the top of the listing.

If you continue reading you'll see the explanation about server controls and how ASP.NET matches them to Html elements.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The book doesn't say why we can access the element without runat=server unless I'm blind. Can you fair use and include that part in your answer?

Comment: @LoveRight On page 136, subtitle: Table Header (Th), Row (Tr) and Detail (Td) it says: You  can also use server-side code to manipulate the th, tr and td tags of a table. Listing 8.9: Manipulating Th, Tr and Td Tags Using Server-Side Code is very similar to yours. Basically a table with a runat="server" and th, tr and td elements with id attributes only (not runat="server") that are effectively accessed from the Page_Load event handler on the top of the listing. If you continue reading you'll see the explanation about server controls and how ASP.NET matches them to Html elements.